# Existence of inverses of linear combinations of bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

If $V$ is a banach space and $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $V$. If $\|T\|< a$ where $a>0$, then is $A=T-aI$ invertible? If so why? We know that if $\|T\|<1$ then $(I-T)$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note
$$
T-aI=-a(I-\frac{1}{a}T)
$$
and by assumption 
$$
\left|\left| \frac{1}{a}T \right|\right|=\frac1{|a|}||T||<1
$$
So $(I-\frac1aT)^{-1}$ is invertible and the inverse of $T-aI$ is then 
$$
-\frac1a(I-\frac1aT)^{-1}
$$

Comment: I assume if $(1-1/aT)$ is invertible, then any scale of that operator is invertible? (i.e we can freely multiply by $-a$ and its fine)

Comment: yes, and you can explicitly give its inverse, as in the above